# meta description homepage with yoast plugin not working in Fishpig Magento

Tags: magento, wordpress, fishpig

We have a Wordpress site that is in our Magento webshop with the module of Fishpig and we are using the Yoast module. In this module we have set a meta description and a meta title for the homepage by the "Titles & meta" part. Now the meta title of the homepage is showed in the Magento blog, but the meta description is not showed in the Magento page.

Does someone have experience with this or knows how to fix this?

Comment: did you got solution for this, actually same thing I am facing in magneto 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested with the latest version of [Magento WordPress Integration](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/) and [WordPress SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) and can see both the custom title and meta description that was entered in WordPress SEO > Titles & Metas > Home inside my integrated blog in Magento.

I recommend upgrading the Magento WordPress Integration extension and the WordPress SEO plugin and the issue should be resolved.